How to avoid SQL content sent from HTML form being blocked by Cloudflare?
I have a POST form that includes a textarea for SQL content. Cloudflare will occasionally classify the content as a SQL Injection attempt and block the submission.
Is there a safe or proper way to submit SQL text as a form element? Should I encode it on the client and decode it on the server?

Looks like a cloudflare-specific question. Don't make it a generic question, because SQL content do not require any special treatment or encoding on a normal host

I believe that you are blocked by Cloudflare WAF Managed rules. There are two options for prevent Cloudflare for blocking you:

You can find out which WAF Managed rule is blocking you and disable it.
Create a specific Custom rule to skip checks for your specific HTTP path (this is more preferable).

To find out the WAF rule affecting you, go to Security -> Events, click on the "Add filter" button under Firewall Events, and add a filter for your path, for example.
More information can be found here: https://developers.cloudflare.com/waf/analytics/security-events/free-plan/
And after you identify exact rule, you need to go Security -> WAF -> Managed rules choose "Cloudflare OWASP Core Ruleset" or "Cloudflare Managed Ruleset" depends of what do you have deployed. Go to the "Browse rules" and put your rule id to the "Search Rules.." field. You will find exactly rule, and you can switch toggle for disabling it.
For example:

For the Custom rule you need to go to Security -> WAF -> Custom rules and press "Create rule". You need to configure rule for example for skip all managed rule for URI contains "example.com/sql-problem-path"
Rule should looks something like this:

More information can be found here: https://developers.cloudflare.com/waf/custom-rules/skip/

I assume that you have access to the cloudflare configuration, of course.
